# What is the redirect_uri for a Facebook authenticated referral from a notification

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, referrals

In order to exchange the code received from a Facebook authenticated referral, a redirect_uri parameter is needed for /oauth/access_token.

In most cases, it seems to work to take everything up until the code= parameter. But this doesn't seems to work for authenticated referrals from a notificaton. The urls look like this:

?ref=noti&code=abc...&fb_source=notification&request_ids=123...&app_request_type=user_to_user

I've tried every combination of query string parameters and nothing seems to work to exchange the code for a token.

What is the redirect_uri for this?